# How to compare below tokenized text useing open NLP with Database column values?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, lucene, opennlp

In my java web application (Jsp + Servlet + hibernate) users can request books. The request goes to the database as a text. After that I tokenize the text using Apache Open NLP. Then I need to compare these tokenized text with books table (the books table has book ID , Book Name , Author , Description) and give most related suggestions to the user. Mostly I need to compare this with book name column and book description column. Is this possible?

```
import opennlp.tools.tokenize.SimpleTokenizer;  

public class SimpleTokenizerExample { 
    public static void main(String args[]){ 

        String sentence = "Hello Guys , I like to read horror stories. If you have any horror story books please share with us. Also my favorite author is Stephen King"; 

        //Instantiating SimpleTokenizer class 
        SimpleTokenizer simpleTokenizer = SimpleTokenizer.INSTANCE;  

        //Tokenizing the given sentence 
        String tokens[] = simpleTokenizer.tokenize(sentence);  

        //Printing the tokens 
        for(String token : tokens) {         
            System.out.println(token);  
        }       
    }  
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to build a recommendation engine that answers the question "if you like this book then we recommend these books"?

Answer (score 5):

Apache OpenNLP can do Natural Language Processing, but the task you describe is Information Retrieval. Take a look at http://lucene.apache.org/solr/.

If you really need to use DB only, you can try to make a query for each token using the LIKE sql keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FROM mytable WHERE token IN description;
```

and rank the lines with higher match.

**How OpenNLP can help you?**

You can use the [OpenNLP Stemmer](http://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/apidocs/opennlp-tools/index.html?opennlp/tools/stemmer/PorterStemmer.html). In that case you can get the stem of the book description and title before adding it to the columns to the database. You also need to stem the query. This will help you with inflections: "car" will match "cars", "car".

You can accomplish the same with the [OpenNLP Lemmatizer](http://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.lemmatizer), but you need a trained model, which is not available today for that module.

Answer (score 2):

just to add to what @wcolen says, some out of the box stemmers exist for various languages in Lucene as well.

Another thing OpenNLP could help with is recognizing book authors names (e.g. Stephen King) via the [NameFinderTool](http://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind) so that you could adjust the query so that your code creates a phrase query for such entities instead of a plain keyword based query (with the result that you won't get results containing Stephen or King but only results containing Stephen King).